# How do I construct a f.collection_select menu with custom options (not from a database)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, custom-fields, collection-select

I'm using Rails 4.2.3.  I would like to construct a select menu in my form, in which both the name and value are the same option and I would like to construct the options from an array.  I tried this

```
<%= f.collection_select :unit, options_for_select([['km'], ['mi']]) %>
```

but got the error

```
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 4..6)
```

How do I construct the above properly?  I would like there to be an additional option with a blank value that reads "Select Unit".

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `select` method instead of the `collection_select`

```
<%= f.select :unit, [['km', 'km'], ['mi', 'mi']] %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do you add the option "Selectd Unit" with an empty value tied to it?

Comment: you can do that with:  `<%= f.select :unit, [['km', 'km'], ['mi', 'mi']], {:prompt => "Select Unit"} %>`